# approve contract in wbnb

Tags: solidity, erc-20-approve, bscscan, wrapped-tokens

I deployed a contract on the bsc network to execute functions on the blockchain then I approved my contract at the wbnb address to make purchases and/or sales from the contract.

[image: Aprobación wbnb]

What am I allowing with that approval? my wbnb have been used by other contracts and my wbnb has been transferred. How can I delimit it or how have they been stolen if I only authorized wbnb?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By calling approve on a token you are authorizing the target contract access to the tokens for the amount approved.

They could transfer the tokens to someone else or burn them.

If you had approved a large amount then the contract could keep transferring any amount deposited until the total approved without requiring new approvals.

Comment: How could I approve so that only my contract receives and sends wbnb without other contracts stealing wbnb from me?

Comment: approving my contract in wbnb address any contract could be sent wbnb from my contract and wallet?

Comment: @JhonatanAlfred87 There's nothing in the standard to prevent an approved contract from forwarding funds to another address. You can always approve a zero amount so the contract won't have access to your funds. An improperly secured contract can be quite dangerous, so you shouldn't approve a contract that you don't trust.